# "Mettere loro a disposizione", "mettere a loro disposizione" oppure "mettere alla loro disposizione"?

Tags: grammar, phrase-choice

Quale tra queste forme, "mettere loro a disposizione", "mettere a loro disposizione" oppure "mettere alla loro disposizione", è quella corretta? Ad esempio, quale sarebbe la frase corretta tra le seguenti?

> - Grazie ai mezzi *messi loro a disposizione*, hanno potuto portare avanti le loro ricerche.
> - Grazie ai mezzi *messi a loro disposizione*, hanno potuto portare avanti le loro ricerche.
> - Grazie ai mezzi *messi alla loro disposizione*, hanno potuto portare avanti le loro ricerche.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Io direi le prime due. A istinto direi che normalmente si userebbe la seconda.

Nella prima "loro" è pronome (== a essi), nella seconda è un possessivo (== di essi).

Per finire, in teoria anche la terza potrebbe essere corretta, ma dubito che qualcuno la userebbe.

Comment: Bè, secondo me nella prima frase il pronome loro significa "per essi" e il formato della frase segue un costrutto un po' arcaico, mentre nella seconda appunto loro significa "di essi", mentre la terza appunto è un po' più scomodamente lunga e contorta anche se non del tutto sbagliata. Se dovessi scegliere, sceglierei la seconda opzione.

Comment: Nella prima "loro" significa "a essi", non ci sono altre possibilità. È la stessa costruzione di "dare un libro" -> "do loro un libro", "mettere a disposizione" -> "metto loro a disposizione". Altri esempi: "fare un favore" -> "faccio loro un favore", "chiedere un'informazione" -> "chiedo loro un'informazione" etc.

Comment: Se nella prima frase "loro" significa "a essi" e non "per essi", allora questo va chiarito. Secondo me, "loro" quà è complemento di argomento, non complemento di distanza. Quindi, guardando la tabella su [questo sito](http://www.scuolaelettrica.it/media/classe1/italiano/italiano1.shtml), la preposizione giusta per descrivere questa situazione è "per", e non "a".

Comment: È un complemento di termine. https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_di_termine. Nota "Talvolta può consistere in un pronome personale complemento (mi, ti, gli, le, ci, vi, loro ecc.)".

Comment: Scusa, è vero che su Wikipedia non c'è, e che forse non ho memorizzato bene i (limitati!) complementi elencati su Wikipedia, ma dal mio punto di vista, da un punto di vista puramente logico, se quel "loro" si traducesse in altre lingue in esattamente lo stesso modo tutte le volte che uno pensasse fosse un semplice complemento di termine, allora i complementi elencati su Wikipedia sarebbero sufficienti.

Comment: Il fatto che il complemento di termine si traduce in altre lingue, secondo la classificazione su Wikipedia, a volte in un modo, e a volte in un altro, significa che i complementi su Wikipedia sono insufficienti per poter tradurre il significato da una lingua all'altra, e secondo me questo non va molto bene. Quando uno studia il Latino, la lista dei complementi da imparare è più lunga e le distinzioni sono molte di più. Questo diomostra la limitazione. Dal punto di vista di Noam Chomsky possono anche coesistere più di una grammatica che descrive una lingua, certe più complete, altre meno.

Comment: Quel loro è **complemento di interesse**: (vantaggio e svantaggio) indica l’essere animato o la cosa a vantaggio o a danno della quale avviene un’azione. Risponde alla domanda: per chi?, per che cosa?, a vantaggio?, a danno di chi?, di che cosa?. Concordi?

Comment: No, ovviamente. È un complemento di termine.

Comment: Va bene @karoshi, posso anche darti ragione, però devo ammettere che non ho capito la differenza tra un complemento di interesse ed un complemento di termine. Sarei felicissimo se tu me lo spiegassi. Grazie.

Comment: Nella pagina che hai citato il complemento di interesse non è nominato, e anch'io è la prima volta che lo sento nominare. Cercando con google, sembra che sia un complemento che si esprimeva in latino con il dativo (così come d'altronde il complemento di termine). Comunque, se il complemento di interesse risponde alla domanda "per chi?" o "a vantaggio di chi?", questo significa che apparirà introdotto da quelle parole e non dal semplice "a", quindi "ho comprato un libro per Mario", "l'incidente è risultato essere a favore di Luigi" ecc. Inoltre ti suggerisco di non complicarti troppo la vita...

Comment: ...di complementi indiretti se ne possono inventare a centinaia, dipendendo dalle sfumature di significato che chi li definisce vuole dare. Credo sia meglio limitarsi a quelli più comuni. In questo caso, ripeto, si tratta particamente senza dubbi di un complemento di termine.

Answer (score 1):

La risposta più corretta secondo me è la seconda: *messi a loro disposizione* suona più fluida rispetto alla terza possibilità, che risulta molto più pesante per la presenza della presposizione articolata *alla*.
Riguardo alla prima possibilità mi sembra che sia scorretta, o che sia una forma in disuso.

Comment: Non capisco perché la prima possibilità dovrebbe essere scorretta.

Comment: Inizialmente mi era sembrata tale, ma leggendo le altre risposte mi sono resa conto che in realtà avevo interpretato male. Ha ragione @karoshi, "loro" ha significati diversi nei due casi.

Comment: Si, anch'io avevo interpretato male la prima frase perchè non mi ero accorto dell'esempio corrispondente alla frase nell'oggetto del messaggio che avrebbe potuto avere un'altro significato. In ogni caso, concordo che la seconda scelta è la più fluida, mentre la prima è arcaica e la seconda è un po meno scorrevole.

Answer (score 0):

Nel primo caso

---

To answer your question:

- The phrase `"mettere loro a disposizione"` means "to make the group of people we are implicitly talking about availabe for the carrying out of some task at hand  (e.g. "mettere a disposizione di "qualcuno"). The phrase must be followed by the preposition word "di", followed by a group of one or more words acting as a noun, which represent the object which is made available to such group of people. Anyways, I was misled by the OP's title and now I realize he was talking about something different: "i mezzi messi loro a disposizione" means "i mezzi messi a disposizione per loro", which means that `the means or tools required for carrying out the task at hand have been made available to someone or some group of people in order to satisfy the needs of the same people, or, possibly the needs of some other group of people`.
- The phrase `"mettere a loro disposizione"` means "`to make (something or several things) available to the group of people we are implicitly talking about`".The phrase must be followed by a group of one or more words acting as a noun, which represent the object which is made available to such group of people.
- The phrase `"mettere alla loro disposizione"` is a more verbose-sounding phrase carrying the same meaning as the second. In practice I would use it if I were trying to make a catchy, slowly-articulated, and emphatic speech and wanted to put particular emphasis on the point I was trying to make. The first construct is shorter than this one and flows better in normal everyday speech.

---

In response to a comment saying that `"loro"` can mean `"to them"` after the word `"mettere"`, I decided to point out the following rather unfortunate thing (which I would't have had the guts to explain were it not for the fact that this newsgroup is filled with experts who understand the fine aspects of Italian language and culture):

With "mettere", the only way to get a "to them" meaning, is to use the words "mettere a", but then the only possibility is the rather vulgar (and hopefully not too shoking!) expression "gliel'ho messo su per il culo" which, is grammatically equivalent to the sentence "l'ho **messo** su per il culo **a** lui/lei/loro" (not to be shocked here, in this sentence the subject can be male or female, the object can be male, female, or a group, and the case where the object can be a group makes you realize, I hope, that this expression conveys the feeling abstractness: regardless of sexuality, you cannot stick something in more than one place at the same time, and, it is precisely this abstract aspect of this very expression which makes it just as likely from anyone towards anyonw irrespective of the geneder of the people involved or their number). OK, enough said for the vulgar side, the grammatical side, and the abstract side. Now the meaning of the expression, which is **not vulgar but on the other hand rather cunning!** and has no equivalent expression in English, so much so that the only way to translate this expression is: "*I've managed to deceive or trick the person or people in question in order to get what I wanted out of them at their own expense or loss and I'm quite happy about it*". Sounds terrible? Well, yes it is. While talking to a group of friends some people could make use of this expression to point out what they have done to the other party which could even be a political party disliked by the group; they could even have befriended the other party in a false manner, or, someone could also use this expression to describe what a false friend could have done to them after they found out the truth, in which case the attitude tends to be one of deep disappointment and resentment! So much for sexual gratification! :-D

---

UPDATE:

Now I see the full example with the words put in context. The first meaning of "mettere loro a disposizione" I gave above, is the one in sentences of the form "mettere loro a disposizione di qualcuno" which is what I originally the OP meant but I overlooked the example that was given. In the sentence "Grazie ai mezzi messi loro a disposizione, hanno potuto portare avanti le loro ricerche." the meaning conveyed is the fact that "i mezzi sono messi a disposizione per loro", hence we are talking about "mettere per" and not "mettere a" (because in English "to" corresponds to both "a" and "per", hence the confusion. Anyways, the expression appearing in the first case is archaic.

**The second expression is the best, more natural choice.**

Regards.

Comment: "Loro" can be a pronoun meaning "to them": "ho dato loro il libro" means "I gave the book to them" (or "I gave them the book"). This is the meaning it has in the OP's original first sentence, so "mettere loro (qualcosa) a disposizione" means "to make (something) available to them".

Comment: Sorry, but you don't go translating those words one their own, you must translate them within the context. When used with the verb "dare", "dare loro" has the meaning you mention, but "mettere" is a different verb, so it doesn't work the same way here. Context must be taken into account. Regards.

Comment: @JohnSonderson: I think that, with the verb "mettere", is the same thing. The pronoun "loro" can be used with lots of verbs!

Comment: Yes, by there in these cases there is an implicit omission of a preposition. While "dare loro" has the meaning "dare a loro", in the archaic first example given by the OP, "mettere loro" means "mettere per loro", not "mettere a loro" which would be different. I have update my post to reflect this subtle difference. Regards.

Comment: John, I cannot absolutely understand the sense of your aside about sodomy and its figurative meanings. If you meant to show that *mettere* + pronoun in the dative case can only be used in that meaning, then I must correct you by simply pointing out that *metterti*, *mettergli*, *metterle* (etc.) *a disposizione* are perfectly good phrases, and so is, if somewhat high-sounding, *metter(e) loro* (as are several other constructions as, say, *metterti davanti un piatto*, *mettergli un vestito* and so on—all meaning *mettere a (lui/lei etc.)*). If you meant something else, it escaped me.

Comment: OK, perhaps my point is not very clear, but I just couldn't find an example where when rephrasing "mettere a lui" in English, you would use the particle "to". For example "metterti davanti un piatto" (to put a plate in front of your self), mettergli un vestito (to dress them up), where is the "to them"? I've never heard any Italians say "mettere a lui/lei", nor "mettere qualcosa a lui/lei", nor "mettere a lui disposizione" which is plain wrong. it just doesn't sound right. Perhaps, "mettere ... per lui", now that would make sense.

Comment: If I ever were hear the words, "mettere a lui/lei", it would only come natural to me to wonder: "mettere a lui cosa? dove? quando? come? e perchè?". Not sure whether I've managed to get my point across, but I'm hoping to be corrected. Thanks.

Comment: You never hear *mettere a lui* (and the analogous for other pronouns) because the idiomatic form is *mettergli*. By the same token, you'll rarely hear *dare a lui*, *vendere a lui*, *stringere a lui (la mano)*, but rather *dargli* etc., unless possibly for emphasis (*voglio dare a lui il regalo, non a lei!*), but the same holds for *mettere* (*voglio mettere a lui il vestito, non a lei*).

Comment: To sum up: *mettere a lui a disposizione (qualcosa)* is ungrammatical; you have to say *mettergli a disposizione (qualcosa)*. On the other hand *metter(e) loro a disposizione* is perfectly fine (if slightly stilted) because there is no enclitic form for *loro*.

Comment: @Dag, sentences can have *grammatical* equivalents, which, although not used in spoken language, have precisely the purpose of conveying the original meaning without altering it. As you point out, in conversation, such equivalents often do not serve any other purpose other than to point grammar features by using an alternative sentence structures. Such alternative sentence structure are often by far and large not alternative choices to the, as you call them, _idiomatic expressions_ used in ordinary language used without an explanation as to what they may mean given in the same language.

Comment: So, your comments above are correct, except for the words "mettere a lui" which in Italian can be used in the peculiar special case (e.g. when attending class in school) where an Italian wants to point out the meaning of the word "mettergli" using more than one word. I believe that in such case, such words could be and would be perfectly correct. Of course, nobody would discuss that particular example in class, but from a purely logical point of view (although not from a sociological one) it makes sense. Regards.